# Django RabbitMQ consumer

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq

I am building a Django application which will be contacted by multiple external applications. Django application is supposed to provide UI and populate the database with the data received from external applications.

First idea was to use `django_rest_framework` but this seemed like creating a tightly coupled system because every external app will have to contact the Django app via REST call.

My other idea is best described with a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGgSg.jpg Several publishers would create messages on an RabbitMQ and my Django would consume those and create appropriate models in the DB.

Is something like this possible? I've used async examples from `pika` library for publisher and consumer and the messages are flowing as expected. Throwing Django in the mix produces errors such as:

```
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label  

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Code excerpts:

```
# pika consumer
def on_message(self, unused_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):
        # invoking view function
        from myapp.views import create_one_foo
        create_one_foo()
        self.acknowledge_message(basic_deliver.delivery_tag)

# views.py
from .models import Foo

def create_one_foo():
    foo = Foo()
    foo.bar = "bar"
    foo.save()
```

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to be related to RabbitMQ. I don't know Django but you should give more details on your Django application so knowledgeable people can answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, it was solved by calling these two lines before you import the models.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "admin.settings")
django.setup()
```

and then

```
from .models import Foo
```

I am still learning django, if I find a detailed explanation I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [this article](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/communicating-between-your-django-apis-using-rabbitmq/) for creating consumer

```
import json
import pika
import django
from sys import path
from os import environ



path.append('/home/john/Dev/SECTION/Likes/Likes/settings.py') #Your path to settings.py file
environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Likes.settings') 
django.setup()
from likes.models import Quote

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', heartbeat=600, blocked_connection_timeout=300))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='likes')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print("Received in likes...")
    print(body)
    data = json.loads(body)
    print(data)

    if properties.content_type == 'quote_created':
        quote = Quote.objects.create(id=data['id'], title=data['title'])
        quote.save()
        print("quote created")
    elif properties.content_type == 'quote_updated':
        quote = Quote.objects.get(id=data['id'])
        quote.title = data['title']
        quote.save()
        print("quote updated")
    elif properties.content_type == 'quote_deleted':
        quote = Quote.objects.get(id=data)
        quote.delete()
        print("quote deleted")
channel.basic_consume(queue='likes', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
print("Started Consuming...")
channel.start_consuming()
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at celery: http://www.celeryproject.org It's a framework helping to create RabbitMQ-based workers

Run a celery worker service on a host where your Django app is. If you need to change the state of Django DB, just import the Django models and put data to the database by the worker. Otherwise you can run celery workers inside Django app.

Comment: If not mistaken. TS want the Django consume data from rabbitmq and celery is behave differently. celery worker will become the consumer and our Django apps become a producer.